# Record global keyboard and mouse event in electron.js desktop app

Tags: node.js, linux, macos, electron, desktop-application

I need some help regarding my project,
I am creating a Desktop app using electron.js, I want to capture keyboard and mouse events (just need a count of keypress events), can you please suggest to me the best solution liberties/package.

I have used iohook, but they have some issue in Linux and mac prebuild system, much appreciate if have any other solutions.

Thanks in advance.